# How to add space between two tables

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two tables in html and want to add spacing between them. Though I don't know how. I am new in html and css and would highly appreciate your help.

```
 <div class="test"> <div class="col-12"> <div class="row">

<table><tr><th>Price</th>{% for l in co %}<td>{{l}}</td>{% endfor %}</tr></table>

<table><tr><th>Amount</th>{% for ye in yes %}<td>{{ye}}</td>{% endfor %}</tr></table>   

</div></div></div>
```

I tried in css

```
.test {padding:30px;}
```

But it moves the table to another row however I want two tables be in 1 row side by side.

Comment: `table { margin: 30px }`

Comment: does not work they are united not split

Comment: why is it not one table? Seems weird the tables are related by rows, but in different tables.

Comment: they are two different tables i just put short version to make it be more clear

Comment: so stick column class on each table? set a margin class? would be better if you mentioned the css framework you are using.

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: yes i am using Bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Put a wrapper div around each table and then style that wrapper div with the following CSS

```
margin: 30px
```

By  wrapper divs I mean something like this:

```
<div class="wrapperDivClass">
    Your table here
</div>
<div class="wrapperDivClass">
    Your table here
</div>
```

In the end your html should look like

```
 <div class="col-12"> <div class="row">


<div class="test">
<table><tr><th>Price</th>{% for l in co %}<td>{{l}}</td>{% endfor %}</tr></table>
</div>

<div class="test">
<table><tr><th>Amount</th>{% for ye in yes %}<td>{{ye}}</td>{% endfor %}</tr></table>   
</div>
</div></div>
```

Your CSS would look like this

```
 .test {
   margin: 30px;
 }
```

For what you are asking, you should use `margin` not `padding`. The margin is the space around an element and the padding is the space between an element and the content inside it.

Try it and let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

You need [CSS margin](https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_margin.asp) in this case.

Besides, I found out that your markup is wrong as you didn't close some tags.

> For every tag you open you must close except for the case of
> self-closing tags like `<br/>`, `<img src="..."/>`, etc.

Below is the revised version to it.

```css
.test table {
  width: 100%;
  background: #ecf0f1;
  /** the below is what is needed for the spacing **/
  margin: 30px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="row">
    
      <table>
        {% for l in co %}
        <tr>
          <th width="30%">Price</th>
          <td width="60%">{{l}}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </table>

      <table>
        {% for ye in yes %}
        <tr>
          <th>Amount</th>
          <td>{{ye}}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </table>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```